# Retornar valor en funcion recursiva PHP

Tags: php

Cuando llamo a la siguiente función, no retorna el valor acumulado en $lista.

```
function fn_recursive($array, $lista = array())
   {

      $allowed_roles = [351];
      $lista = array();
      foreach ($array as $key => $value) :
         foreach ($value as $k => $v) :
            if (is_array($v)) :
               $this->fn_recursive($v);
            else :
               if (in_array($value->role_id, $allowed_roles)) :
                  array_push($lista, $value->rut);
                  break;
               endif;
            endif;
         endforeach;
      endforeach;
   return $lista
   }
```

Alguna idea de como controlar esto? Al llamar nuevamente la función la lista queda en vacia.

Answer (score 0):

El segundo parametro deberia ser el que lleve la lista cargada y no sobreescribirla en la funcion. Al lamar a la funcion recursiva, debes incluir la lista actual en el segundo parametro.

function fn_recursive($array, $lista = array())
{

```
  $allowed_roles = [351];
  // $lista = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) :
     foreach ($value as $k => $v) :
        if (is_array($v)) :
           $this->fn_recursive($v, $lista); // incluir lista actual
        else :
           if (in_array($value->role_id, $allowed_roles)) :
              array_push($lista, $value->rut);
              break;
           endif;
        endif;
     endforeach;
  endforeach;
```

return $lista
}